# Attempted removal and reinstallation of LibreOffice failed

Tags: command-line, 16.04, libreoffice

I desperately need to get LibreOffice installed and useable on my system (Ubuntu 16.04). I had tried to install it my self using terminal probably using (cannot remember specifically):

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

But I was not able to find and open any of the libreoffice software. So I tried using the Ubuntu software manager GUI to install it instead. On searching for 'libreoffice', the manager displayed the option to "remove" programs: writer, calc, draw, impress and base; suggesting that these are already installed. But I was not able to open them using terminal i.e. by writing:

```
libreoffice writer
```

So I ran the following in terminal (terminal lines in image 2 begin from the last line in image 1). Apologies, but my lack of "reputation points" won't allow me to take more than two screen shots, so I have written the terminal lines which were displayed before those in terminal screen-shot 1 (but the formatting for this text box and the ensuing published material is ridiculous):

```
vascofmbull@vascofmbull-ThinkPad-S2:~$** sudo dpkg -r libreoffice
[sudo] password for vascofmbull: 
(Reading database ... 219354 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libreoffice (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1~xenial0) ...

vascofmbull@vascofmbull-ThinkPad-S2:~$ man dpkg
vascofmbull@vascofmbull-ThinkPad-S2:~$ libreoffice
The program 'libreoffice' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install libreoffice-common
vascofmbull@vascofmbull-ThinkPad-S2:~$ sudo apt install libreoffice-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-dejavu fonts-sil-gentium fonts-sil-gentium-basic libabw-0.1-1v5
  libcdr-0.1-1 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libe-book-0.1-1 libeot0 libetonyek-0.1-1
  libfreehand-0.1-1 libmspub-0.1-1 libmwaw-0.3-3 libodfgen-0.1-1
  liborcus-0.10-0v5 libpagemaker-0.0-0 libreoffice-gtk
  libreoffice-report-builder-bin librevenge-0.0-0 libvisio-0.1-1
  libwpd-0.10-10 libwpg-0.3-3 libwps-0.4-4
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-style-breeze libreoffice-style-hicontrast
  libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-oxygen libreoffice-style-sifr
  libreoffice-style-tango
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libreoffice-common
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 135 not to upgrade.
65 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/22.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 85.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 219351 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu1~xenial0_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:5.2.2-0ubuntu1~xenial0) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a5.2.2-0ubuntu1~xenial0_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-debian-menus 4.1.1-9775
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/program/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
```

[image: terminal screen-shot 1]
[image: terminal screen-shot 2]

I'm sorry for the mess that I produced in the terminal. But I figured it would be best to show everything that I did.

Any suggestions as to how I can install and use libreoffice on my system?

Comment: The correct command to start writer from a terminal would be `soffice --writer`.  You can also start the program graphically be pressing the meta key and searching for writer.  Can you try this please, and report any error messages given?

Answer (score -1):

Download LibreOffice from the official website and install using `sudo dpkg -i (the .deb file name)`